# Want to add transition-delay on hovering my mega drop-down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, megamenu

I am trying to add transition-delay property on my dropdown menu but it's not working. I don't know why and I have also searched different questions on stackoverflow but none of them is working for me. Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="header">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 1</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 2</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 3</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

My css code here:

```
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  
}
```

[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/revutujuba/edit?html,css,output) for my code

I have also used the **visibility** property instead of **display** but it's not working for me. Your answer will be a great addition to my knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any **animation/transition** in your code.
And as you know you can't animate the **display** property. Instead use **animation**:

```css
/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  /* addition to your existing code */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
}

/* Mega Menu header, if needed */
.dropdown-content .header {
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /* addition to your existing code */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 1s;
  
}
/* addition to your existing code */
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;

}

/* Style links inside the columns */
.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="header">
              <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 1</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 2</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h3>Category 3</h3>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To learn more about animations/transitions you can look at:
[transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Thank you soo much @Seltjoek for your addition. Worked perfectly.